# Restore backup from 'dd' (possibly problem with softRAID HDDs)

Tags: linux, backup, dd

I have 2 servers, Ubuntu 18.04. First is my main server which I want to backup. Second is tested server with Ubuntu 18.04 - KS-4 Server - Atom N2800 - 4GB DDR3 1066 MHz - SoftRAID 2x 2To SATA - when I want test my backup.

I make backup by 'dd' command and nextly I download this backup (wget) by server 2 (490gb, ~ 24hours downloading).

Now I want test my backup so I tried:

```
dd if=sdadisk.img of=/dev/sdb
```

I get:

```
193536+0 records in
193536+0 records out
99090432 bytes (99 MB, 94 MiB) copied, 5.06239 s, 19.6 MB/s
```

But nothing will change.

fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x8efed6c9

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *          4096    1050623    1046528  511M fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2          1050624 3905974271 3904923648  1.8T fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda3       3905974272 3907020799    1046528  511M 82 Linux swap / Solaris


GPT PMBR size mismatch (879097967 != 3907029167) will be corrected by w(rite).
Disk /dev/sdb: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: B3B13223-6382-4EB6-84C3-8E66C917D396

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1       2048   1048575   1046528   511M EFI System
/dev/sdb2    1048576   2095103   1046528   511M Linux RAID
/dev/sdb3    2095104 878039039 875943936 417.7G Linux RAID
/dev/sdb4  878039040 879085567   1046528   511M Linux swap


Disk /dev/md1: 511 MiB, 535756800 bytes, 1046400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/md2: 1.8 TiB, 1999320842240 bytes, 3904923520 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

lsblk -l

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk
├─sda1    8:1    0   511M  0 part
│ └─md1   9:1    0   511M  0 raid1 /boot
├─sda2    8:2    0   1.8T  0 part
│ └─md2   9:2    0   1.8T  0 raid1 /
└─sda3    8:3    0   511M  0 part  [SWAP]
sdb       8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk
├─sdb1    8:17   0   511M  0 part
├─sdb2    8:18   0   511M  0 part
├─sdb3    8:19   0 417.7G  0 part
└─sdb4    8:20   0   511M  0 part
```

I think the problem is with configuration of disks on server 2, specifically with 'Linux raid' between them. I searching how change its, I testing commands like 'mdadm...' but it's not working like I expected. So I have questions:

1. How change 'Linux raid' from 2 HDDS to 1 HDD with current system and 2 HDD clear, when I can test my backup properly?
2. It's generally possible to restore backup 490GB on 1.8TB?
3. I selected the best option to full linux backup?

Answer (score 0):

To touch on question #3 "I selected the best option to full linux backup?"

You are using the correct tool, but not the correct items to use the **dd** command on.

It appears you created a .img file for your sda drive (which is normally only used to create a bootable disk and not a full backup of the drive.

If you want to create a full backup, for example of /dev/sda you would run the following:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb
```

But In your case your /dev/sda drive is a twice the size of your /dev/sdb drive so you might want to consider backing up important files using **tar** as well as compressing the backup using either **gzip or bzip2**.

Comment: No. I backup 490GB SSD1 on 490GB SSD2 with dd if=/dev/sda of=partition.img. Next, I transfer partition.img to server 2 with 2 HDDs 1.8T and softRaid. And on 2 server I want test my backup of server 1 - it's real situation, when my SSD1 crashed and I want simple and fast restore my server (backup) on new machine.

Comment: You might need to expand the partitions to utilize full disk size. Plus if its RAID perhaps you should restore to raid device?